# Array Sorting using array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
$sortPattern= array(1,2,8,4);
$toSort = array(2,4,8,18,16,26);
```

Now, we have to sort `$toSort` array according to `$sortPattern`.

We should have the result

```
$result = array(2,8,4,18,16,26);
```

Does anyone know the function to do this, or should we have to write our own function to perform this?

Comment: hmm... I can't see how the pattern relates to the final sort order? But you can sort in whatever order you want using `usort()`.

Comment: Please specify the syntax of your sort pattern a bit, it's not really clear what it should express.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would have to write your own sort function, and apply it with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). In your callback, you would do something like:

```
if ( $a == $b ) {
    return 0;
} elseif ( array_search( $a, $sortPattern ) < array_search( $b, $sortPattern ) {
    return -1;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Don't foget to handle the case where a and/or b isn't in the sort pattern.

Answer (score 0):

What influence does `$sortPattern` have on `$toSort` ?

It looks like maybe:

```
$result = array_merge(
    array_intersect($sortPattern, $toSort), // 2, 8, 4
    array_diff($toSort, $sortPattern)       // 18, 16, 26
);
```